# Using SugarCRM for free of cost and do the necessary changes

Tags: php, licensing, sugarcrm

I want to use SugarCRM  (I downloaded the free source code) for my client and do the necessary changes wherever required.
  In their domain they mentioned like we need to purchase the software. I am not sure why to purchase when we get the free source code from them and can do the changes.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about licensing and legal issues, not programming or software development. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/274964/1402846) for details, and the [help/on-topic] for more.

Comment: I agree, it is off topic. Should be closed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several SugarCRM editions, see http://www.sugarcrm.com/crm/products/editions.html

If you don't need the professional features or support from the devs, you don't need to buy it.

Comment: Yes we dont need their professional features, as they mentioned around 85% are comes with free edition.

Answer (score 0):

> Sugar Community Edition is licensed under version 3 of the AGPL. Sugar Professional Edition and Enterprise Edition are distributed under a commercial license.

[Source](http://www.sugarcrm.com/crm/community/sugarcrm-community.html)

[AGPL 3](http://www.gnu.org/licenses/agpl.html) is a free software license (See [the four freedoms/The Free Software Definition](http://www.gnu.org/philosophy/free-sw.html)). You don't need to pay royalties to the licensor for making changes to the software if you could already acquired the code.

However, Sugar CRM does offer a free trial for *Sugar Pro* which is not licensed under AGPL but under a commercial license that might have restrictions for making changes to the software.

Answer (score 0):

You can also follow Open Source SugarCRM version on github: https://github.com/sugarcrm/sugarcrm_dev

You can fork it and contribute back if you want to.